# how can i filter data which only have desired width on data like this in laravel 8

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, explode

i want to combine the data and display it based on the width value of each item, with a table like this how can i do that

```
 my controller
public function test(){

    // $item = '20/20/20';
    // $dimension = 'width/height/depth';
    $item = TestItem::join('t_dimensions','t_items.dimension_id', '=', 't_dimensions.id')->get();

    //foreach($item as $item){
        //$size = explode('/',$item->size);
        //$item = explode('/',$item->dimension);
    //}

    return response->json($item);
}
```

table dimensions

| id | dimension |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Height/Width |
| 2 | Width/Height/Depth |

table items

| id | item | size | dimension_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | mistar | 20/5 | 1 |
| 2 | board | 50/100 | 1 |
| 3 | board | 80/50 | 1 |
| 4 | pipe | 120/50/80 | 2 |
| 5 | plate | 200/100 | 1 |

i want to display data like this, only display data that has width >= 100

> 1. board   Height 50, Width 100

> 2. pipe    Width 100,Height 50, Depth 80

> 3. plate    Width 200, Height 100

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you, apply the logic in blade file in foreach loop

```
 @foreach ($items as $product )
@Php
  [$width,$height,$depth] = explode("/",$product->size);
@endphp
@if ($width >= 100)
 <li>ID: {{ $product->item }}, Width {{ $width}} , depth {{$depth}}</li>
@endif
```

@endforeach

Comment: I think it would be easier to create like that, but the table I got from other system data is like this and I should try to generate output like that

Comment: @rista apply the logic in blade file instead of controller

Comment: thanks, khatib for the response but the result not not appropriate

Comment: @rista , if you just copy and past my code , it will not work because in foreach loop i am using $items instead of $item. Actually i am giving you the idea how to fetch width, height and depth in blade file. do some changes in my code and it will work

Comment: hi khatib, i need filter data witdth where value is >= 100

Comment: @rista add an if condition that will allow to render values if the width is creater than 100

Comment: i try it and show "Undefined variable: width"

Comment: test your code step by step. First of all try to fetch data without any filter like (width>=100)etc. and do not break "size" in height width etc. if it work then break "size" in height, width , depth . if it works then add logic of (width > = 100). check carefully if you missed $ sign in [$width,$height,$depth]